# Jquery Dropdown List not sliding up after mouse leave

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I was basically trying to create a drop-down list with jquery. I was successful in achieving but came across with a slight problem. Here's the code

**HTML**

```
<div class="dropdown_heading">
      text
    </div>
      <div class="dropdown_container">
          <div class="">
            <a href="#">Competition1</a>
          </div>
          <div class="">
            <a href="#">Competition2</a>
          </div>
          <div class="">
            <a href="#">Competition3</a>
          </div>

      </div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".dropdown_heading").mouseenter(function(){
    $(".dropdown_container").slideDown();
  });

    $(".dropdown_container").mouseleave(function(){
      $(".dropdown_container").slideUp();
    });
});
```

Once I hover over the dropdown_heading the dropdown shows-up and I'm able to navigate over it but the only way the it slides back up is if i actually have the cursor in the dropdown_container. If I try to slide it up removing the mouse from dropdown_heading, the dropdown is still visible. How would I be able to slide the submenu back up when the mouse leaves both div_container and div_heading?

I've tried to execute this function but therefore I am unable to navigate over the container. Thanks.

```
 $(".dropdown_heading").mouseleave(function(){
      $(".dropdown_container").slideUp();
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a timer based solution like

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var $target = $(".dropdown_container");
  $('.dropdown_heading').hover(function() {
    clearTimeout($target.data('hoverTimer'));
    $target.stop(true, true).slideDown(500);
  }, function() {
    var timer = setTimeout(function() {
      $target.stop(true, true).slideUp();
    }, 200);
    $target.data('hoverTimer', timer);
  });

  $target.hover(function() {
    clearTimeout($(this).data('hoverTimer'));
  }, function() {
    $(this).stop(true, true).slideUp();
  });
});
```

```css
.dropdown_container {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown_heading">
  text
</div>
<div class="dropdown_container">
  <div class="">
    <a href="#">Competition1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="">
    <a href="#">Competition2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="">
    <a href="#">Competition3</a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `toggleClass()` method toggles between adding and removing one or more class names from the selected elements.

This method checks each element for the specified class names. The class names are added if missing, and removed if already set - This creates a toggle effect..

Try this,

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".dropdown_heading").mouseenter(function(){
    $(".dropdown_container").toggle();
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown_heading">
      text
    </div>
      <div class="dropdown_container">
          <div class="">
            <a href="#">Competition1</a>
          </div>
          <div class="">
            <a href="#">Competition2</a>
          </div>
          <div class="">
            <a href="#">Competition3</a>
          </div>

      </div>
```

Comment: Still with the same problem, I have to mouse over text to hide the competitions again. My idea was once you take the cursor out of both text and competitions, the dropdown would disappear